# Design Priority Encoder using only NAND and NOR Gates

Tags: digital-logic, encoder, logic-level

I'm trying to build an 8-to-3 priority encoder using only nand and nor gates. Below is a 4-2 priority encoder, however it is using only ands, ors, and nots. If I have specific activation levels (some are low and others are high), how would this affect the design of the encoder?

[image: Wikipedia's 4-2 PE]

Comment: How come A2 is not connected?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the truth table of the function you want then find out the logic function that fits this table using k-maps:
http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/elessonshtml/Logic/Logic3.html

Then once you have that function, you can convert it to NAND and NOR terms using DeMorgans Square. Then implement that function using your gates and you are done! You can find detailed write ups in most Digital Design textbooks.

Comment: Here is a detailed description of how to convert to NAND and NOR terms" http://www.ece.gatech.edu/academic/courses/ece2030/readings/gates/mixed-logic.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You should write the function down and find its Karnaugh map. After than, all you need to do is find its and-or implementation. And-or implemetation is the same with nand-nand implementation. Replace both ands and ors with nands. There is your design.

Comment: "Replace both ands and ors with nands". Doesn't this change the activation levels/boolean values of the design?

Comment: AND - OR is equivalent to NAND - NAND.  And it does change the logic from positive to negative.  A NAND is a Negative OR.